# Is my Regex more efficient than my forEach?

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I need to remove spaces, `\t` and `\n` from all strings. I have 2 options, and I am wondering which is more efficient or why I should choose a specific solution. 
I am asking, because I am not a huge fan of regex (not my strongest area), yet anytime I Google a problem I have, a regex is usually the top answer. I prefer to code out a solution myself, but if this is not the best approach, I will change my mindset and get better at regex.

**Solution 1 (REGEX):**

```
function fixString(str) {
  str = str.replace(/(\\t|\\n )/g, "");
  return str;
}
```

**Solution 2 (forEach - my preferred option):**

```
function fixString(str) {
  let mapEscapeChars = {
    " ": "",
    "\t": "",
    "\n": ""
  }
  let keys = Object.keys(mapEscapeChars);
  keys.forEach(function(element) {
    str = str.replace(element, mapEscapeChars[element]);
  });
  return str;
}
```

**Example Strings:**

```
" \t1234g" -->>> "1234g"

"\ng1234\t " -->>> "g1234"
```

Comment: I would hazard a guess the regex is more efficient as you are traversing the string once as opposed to three times. However, beware of premature optimisation. Unless you are using extremely long string and replacing in a large loop, stick with the most maintainable. For me that would be the regex, but maybe not for you.

Comment: Use the regex, its way faster then iterating through the string twice. Regex is written at a low level.

Comment: The regex shown won't do what you want. It should use `\t` and `\n`, not `\\t` and `\\n`, and you're missing a `|` before the space. Why not just use `/\s/g` to match all whitespace characters, or use a character class `/[\t\n ]/g`?

Comment: @nnnnnn as mentioned, this is not my strongest area, but what I can say is that testing this regex found 3 matches is an example string  ' \tg1234\n'. When I change the regex to single backslash, it finds one match, the space.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. The regex shown in the question would match a backslash character followed by a plain "t", *not* a tab character. How are you creating the string that you're doing the replacement on?

Comment: The strings are just being pulled from a db, and I have to remove the escaped characters and space. It is my understanding they are tabs/newlines etc. I agree it does not make much sense, but I use regexr.com to test on the fly, and it is showing me what I stated.

Comment: Here you can see what I'm saying is correct for JS: https://jsfiddle.net/qb6go9f8/ It sounds like you're confusing string literals with string values. If the string in the DB contains an actual backslash character followed by a "t" character then JS won't treat that as an escape sequence.

Comment: Another regex tool to add to your belt demonstrating @nnnnnn s point : https://regex101.com/r/uY3fzJ/1 vs https://regex101.com/r/HFbHwF/1

Comment: If you really just want to strip out all different spacing characters `str.replace(/\s/g, "")` is the way to go.

Comment: The comments are rather irrelevant to the question (although you really should compare apples to apples). Did you try to just benchmark the two options?

Comment: Use jsperf to compare both solutions. Here is a sample : https://jsperf.com/stackoverflow-44125676/1

Comment: and [another](https://jsperf.com/regex-vs-foreach/1) that uses large input...

Comment: @jmcgui05 if my answer was helpful, please accept it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I work quite a bit with regexes.  Although challenging to learn they can be very powerful.  In my experience it's often easier to write a for loop like you have in example 2.  You can easily then make an array or construct one:

```
myarray = "a,b,c"
mystring = "words and stuffs for a and for b"
for i in myarray:
    mystring = re.sub(i, "", mystring)
```

Easy to read.  However, loops can be inefficient once you start throwing hundreds of items in your list.  So then I would recommend:

```
mystring = "words and stuffs for a and for b"
mystring = re.sub("[abc]+", "", mystring)
```

One long ugly regex becomes much faster vs having to loop many times.  Another option if you are going to run the SAME regex many times is to compile it.  It is different in many languages.  But say you have a regex to look for apples and you are going to search it over many strings:

```
regex = re.compile("apples")
for word in (huge_list_of_strings):
    if re.search(regex, word):
        print ("you found it!)
```

That way the regex gets made once by the engine, and then it just runs.  It doesn't have to internally 'build' the regex each time.

So there is really no wrong way, just depends on what you really want :) sometimes easy to read is worth a few seconds, sometimes it's not!

In your case I would probably just do something along the lines of:

```
str = str.replace(/[\t\d]/g, "");  --may need to do \\t\\d  not sure with this language
```